# Finding $x$'s parity in the discrete log problem

Tags: modular-arithmetic, finite-field

Suppose $p$ is prime, and $g, a\in\mathbb F_p$ are given elements with $g$ a primitive root. The discrete log problem poses the task of finding an integer $x$ such that $g^x=a$. Show that even if $x$ cannot be recovered, one can check if $x$ is odd or even by inspecting the element $a^{(p-1)/2}$.

I'm not sure how to approach this question. I tried $g^{x(p-1)/2} = a^{(p-1)/2} = 1$.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "tried"? The equation $a^{(p-1)/2}\overset{\text?}=1$ does not necessarily hold.

Comment: In particular, what is $g^{x(p-1)/2}$ if $x$ is even?  What is it if it is odd?

Comment: The question is strongly connected with Legendre Symbol of a, as you observe it.
If Legendre symbol of a is +1, then x is even!

Comment: if x is even then 2 divides it but I don't know what that means. does it imply that it's equal to 1? by fermat's little theorem

Comment: What happens when x is odd?

Comment: Write $x=2k+\epsilon$; $\epsilon$ is the parity
Then $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=g^{x.\frac{p-1}{2}}=g^{\epsilon.\frac{p-1}{2}}$ = +1 (if x even) or =-1 (if x odd).
This is what I claimed above, above about the connexion with Legendre symbol. And to complete observe that g is a primitive element and then is of order p-1.

Comment: How is it equal to -1 if x is odd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Claim.** $a^{(p-1)/2} = 1$ if and only if $x$ is even.

*Proof.* If $x$ is even, let $x = 2y$. Then
$$a^{(p-1)/2} = (g^x)^{(p-1)/2} = g^{2y(p-1)/2} = (g^{p-1})^y = 1^y = 1.$$

If $x$ is odd, let $x = 2y+1$. Then
$$a^{(p-1)/2} = g^{(2y+1)(p-1)/2} = \dots$$
(remember here that $g$ is a generator of $\mathbf{F}_p^*$).

Comment: If x is odd, we are left with $g^{(p-1)/2}$. However i fail to understand what that is equal to. I know $g^{(p-1)} = 1$ since $g$ is a generator

Comment: You don't care what it is equal to. ;) What is important is what it is *not* equal to.

Comment: By the way, $g^{p-1} = 1$ is true for any $g$. The fact that $g$ is a generator implies something more than that.

Comment: One note:  This only works when $p$ isn't a *safe prime* ($p = 2q + 1$).  If $p$ is safe, then you're raising $a$ to it's own order, so you always get $1$.

Comment: @Bren2010 This works for all primes. If the order of $a$ is $(p-1)/2$, then $x$ is even, so of course the result is $1$.

Comment: @fkraiem  ... No it doesn't, and I explained why.  Empirical example:  $11$ is a safe prime, and the subgroup we want in it is of order $5$.  If you raise anything in that subgroup to the power $5 = (p - 1)/2$, you're just going to get 1.  Otherwise put:  Every element of the subgroup is a quadratic residue.

Comment: @Bren2010 What are you talking about? We are working in the full group $\mathbf{F}_p^*$, which in your example has order $10$, not $5$.

Comment: @mikerussel Oh and by the way, the fact that $a^{(p-1)/2} = -1$ if $x$ is odd follows simply from what you have found. You have $a^{(p-1)/2} = g^{(p-1)/2}$, so $(a^{(p-1)/2})^2 = g^{p-1} = 1$, meaning that $a^{(p-1)/2}$ is a root of the polynomial $X^2-1$. Since we are over a field, this polynomial has at most two roots, which are easily seen to be $1$ and $-1$. Since $a^{(p-1)/2}$ is not $1$, it must be $-1$.