# How to calculate Legendre Symbol in secp256k1 Elliptic Curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, modular-arithmetic, finite-field

[In this answer by fkraiem](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/22831/59949)  he proves a property that:

> $a^{(p-1)/2} = 1$ if and only if $x$ is even

But this doesn't seem to work in my test with the secp256k1 Elliptic Curve. Here is my Python 2 code:

ECLib.py:

```
P = 2**256 - 2**32 - 2**9 - 2**8 - 2**7 - 2**6 - 2**4 - 1
N = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141
Gx = 55066263022277343669578718895168534326250603453777594175500187360389116729240
Gy = 32670510020758816978083085130507043184471273380659243275938904335757337482424
GPoint = (int(Gx),int(Gy))
Acurve = 0

def legendreSymbol(a,p=P): #Legendre Symbol Calculation
    ls = pow(a, (p - 1) / 2, p)
    if ls == p - 1: return -1
    else: return ls

def modinv(a,n): # Extended Euclidean Algorithm
    lm, hm = 1,0
    low, high = a%n,n
    while low > 1:
        ratio = high/low
        nm = hm - lm * ratio
        new = high - low * ratio
        hm = lm
        high = low
        lm = nm
        low = new
    return lm % n

def ECadd(xp,yp,xq=Gx,yq=Gy): # EC point addition
    m = ((yq-yp) * modinv(xq-xp,P))%P
    xr = (m*m-xp-xq)%P
    yr = (m*(xp-xr)-yp)%P
    return (xr,yr)

def ECdouble(xp,yp): # EC point doubling
    LamNumer = 3*xp*xp+Acurve
    LamDenom = 2*yp
    Lam = (LamNumer * modinv(LamDenom,P)) % P
    xr = (Lam*Lam-2*xp) % P
    yr = (Lam*(xp-xr)-yp) % P
    return (xr,yr)
```

Test.py:

```
import ECLib

Point = (ECLib.Gx, ECLib.Gy)
Deg = 1

print 'Degree of G \t\t\t Legendre Symbol'

for i in range(8):
  Point = ECLib.ECdouble(Point[0], Point[1])
  Deg = Deg * 2
  print '\t' + str(Deg) + '\t\t\t\t' + str(ECLib.legendreSymbol(Point[0]))
```

Output:

```
Degree of G                      Legendre Symbol
        2                               1
        4                               -1
        8                               -1
        16                              1
        32                              -1
        64                              -1
        128                             1
        256                             1
```

As I am doubling, the power of G is always even, so Legendre Symbol should always be 1 but that is not the case. Why is that?

Comment: You are testing the Legendre symbol on x coordinates of elliptic curve points. Legendre symbol shouldn't be used like that. You can't imply the "degree of G" by looking at x-coordinates. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @kelalaka but do you know if the same properties apply to elliptic curves?

Comment: No, the same properties do not apply to the elliptic curves themselves (at least, if we're working with a curve with an odd number of points, or a subgroup with odd order - we almost always do).

Comment: @Ruggero I was trying to find the parity of x by legendre symbol but finding the right legendre symbol is not possible for this elliptic curve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer extends [@poncho's comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/235335).

The property “ $a^{(p-1)/2}=1\text{ if and only if }x\text{ is even}$ ” stated in the [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/22831/555) linked in the question is for the [multiplicative group modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group) an odd prime $p$, and assumes $a=g^x$ with $g$ a generator of that group. The group, thus generator $g$, has even order $p-1$ (the $-1$ is because $0$ is not a member of the group). That even order of $g$ is essential for proving the property.

The present question is for an [elliptic curve group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#Elliptic_curves_over_finite_fields) over [prime field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)#Fields_of_prime_characteristic) $\mathbb F_\mathtt{P}$ of prime order $\mathtt{N}$, and a generator $\mathtt{G}$ (all given numerically). That happens to be [secp256k1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.4.1). Customarily, elliptic curve groups are noted additively rather than multiplicatively. Indeed $A=x\,\mathtt{G}$ in the elliptic curve group parallels $a=g^x$ in multiplicative group modulo $p$. The point at infinity $\mathcal O$ parallels $1$. $G$ parallels $g$. $N$ parallels $p-1$.

The property “ $((N-1)/2)\,\mathtt{A}=\mathcal O\text{ if and only if }x\text{ is even}$ ” *would* parallel $a^{(p-1)/2}=1$ *if* $N$ was even. But it's not! That would require a different elliptic curve (and then, for a curve used in [ECDSA](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsection.4.1), $G$ would be chosen of prime order, thus not a generator of the whole curve).

And there's no substitute. Using ${(\mathtt{A}_X)}^{(\mathtt{P}-1)/2}=1$ comes out of nowhere, and does not work, as the test in the question illustrates (and @poncho generalizes in [another comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/235339)).

For the parameters of secp256k1, there is no known computationally feasible method to guess the parity of $x$ from $x\,\mathtt{G}$ alone for random $x\in[1,\mathtt{N})$. Argument: If there was a practical method for this consistently working significantly better than a random guess, that method could demonstrably be leveraged to compute the private key matching any public key.

Comment: "And there's no substitute. Using $({\mathtt{A}_X})^{(\mathtt{P}-1)/2}$ comes out of nowhere, and does not work, as the test in the question illustrates."; actually, it cannot work.  A valid $\mathtt{A}_X$ value corresponds to two elliptic curve points, and for sec256k1, one has even $x$ and the other has odd $x$ - that test has no way to determine which. Hence, there is no possible test to determine the lsbit of $x$ which examines only $\mathtt{A}_X$

Comment: Don't get me wrong but how can the legendre symbol still be so precise to always give 1 or p-1 in my example in the question? That's the natural outputs expected from the calculation of legendre symbol.

Comment: @DevanshuLinux: your `legendreSymbol` has result $r$ such that $r≡a^{(\mathtt{P}-1)/2}\pmod{\mathtt{P}}$. Thus $r^2≡{\left(a^{(\mathtt{P}-1)/2}\right)}^2≡a^{\mathtt{P}-1}\pmod{\mathtt{P}}$. By Fermat's Little Theorem, since $\mathtt{P}$ of secp256k1 is prime, and since $a\not\equiv0\pmod{\mathtt{P}}$ for your inputs $a$ that are X coordinates on secp256k1, it holds $r^2≡1\pmod{\mathtt{P}}$. That's a second degree equation, thus it has only two solutions in the output set $[-1,p-1)$ of your `legendreSymbol`, and these are $-1$ and $1$. That's why your $r$ is always one of these.

Comment: ohhh! @fgrieu thanks a lot, mate!